# BeautifulSoup: Selector not extracting the right data - Yahoo Scrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the text from an element whose class value contains compText. The problem is that it extracts everything but the text that I want.

The CSS selector identifies the element correctly when I use it in the developer tools.

I'm trying to scrape the text that appears in Yahoo SERP when the query entered doesn't have results.

1. If my query is (quotes included)  "klsf gl glkjgsdn lkgsdg" nothing is displayed expect the complementary text "We did not find results blabla" and the Selector extract the data correctly
2. If my query is (quotes included) "based specialty. Blocks. Organosilicone.  Reference". Yahoo will add ads because of the keyword "Organosilicone" and that triggers the behavior described in the first paragraph.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p="
query = '"based specialty chemicals. Blocks. Organosilicone.  Reference"'
r = requests.get(url + query) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for EachPart in soup.select('div[class*="compText"]'):
    print (EachPart.text)
```

What could be wrong?

Thx,

EDIT: The text extracted seems to be the defnition of the word "Organosilicone" which I can find on the SERP.

EDIT2: This is a snippet of the text I get: "The products created and produced by ‘Specialty Chemicals’ member companies, many of which are Small and Medium Enterprises, stem from original and continuous innovation. They drive the low-carbon, resource-efficient and knowledge based economy of the future." and a screenshot of the SERP when I use my browser [image]

Comment: When I searched for *"based specialty chemicals. Blocks. Organosilicone.  Reference"* on Yahoo, I got many (non ad) results, and your code is correctly printing the text of those results. So, what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I've edited my question. Please refer to edit 2. Thank you.BTW, I don't want to scrape the results but the complementary text.

Comment: Have a look at the search results that I'm getting. They are the same as what your script is getting. [https://imgur.com/a/jLvD22Q](https://imgur.com/a/jLvD22Q)

Comment: Hum, that sucks. My script is supposed to extract only the text that is inside a class that name contains "compText".

Comment: The text of those search results also have *compText* as a class. That explains your output. I don't know why you are seeing different search results. Maybe try incognito mode?

Comment: Same results in incognito, unfortunately. I'm lost :(